# Thermodynamics: Potential functions for adiabatically stretched ideal spring

Tags: thermodynamics, potential-energy, spring

Let's say you have an ideal spring being stretched adiabatically by applying a force $f$:

$f = k(L - L_0)$

> First, I want to find $k$ as a thermodynamic derivative.

I'm not really sure how to do this. I know I could say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial L} = k$, but I'm not really sure if this counts as a 'thermodynamic derivative.'

My second attempt was by trying to think of $U$ as a function of $S, L$ (I do not believe pressure and volume are relevant as is usually used in $U$) as:

$$dU = TdS + fdL = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial S})_L dS + (\frac{\partial U}{\partial L})_S dL$$
so that $$k = (\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial L^2})_S$$
Would this be considered an appropriate thermodynamic derivative?

> Next, I'm trying to derive the relationship:
>   $$(\frac{\partial T}{\partial L})_S = -\frac{k T}{C_f} (\frac{\partial L}{\partial T})_f$$

This one I'm not really sure where to start. Assuming my differential form of $U$ is correct, I can find the Hemholtz function fairly easily to get:

$$dF = dU - d(TS) = fdL - SdT = (\frac{\partial F}{\partial L})_T dL -(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T})_L dT$$

Neither of these have $f$ involved as a differential, so I don't know how I'd find $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial T})_f$.

Clearly the heat capacity has to come in at some point, I'd like to say that:

$$C_f = T(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T})_f \implies \frac{T}{C_f} =  (\frac{\partial T}{\partial S})_f$$

Using the Hemholtz function, I can find the Maxwell relation:

$$(\frac{\partial T}{\partial f})_L = -(\frac{\partial L}{\partial S})_T$$

At this point, I feel like i'm just throwing derivatives all over the place with no real direction. Any help on either part would be very appreciated.

Comment: $k=(\partial f/\partial L)_{S}=(\partial^2 U/\partial L^2)_{S}$ is correct (for the adiabatic spring constant). Keep working at it; you're almost there. Try using the triple product rule with $(\partial T/\partial S)_f$.

Comment: @chemomechanics: when I wrote the triple product, I got $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial S})_T (\frac{\partial T}{\partial f}_S = -\frac{T}{C_f}$, however I'm not sure how to continue. I can't expand any of the derivatives in another triple product, so I'm assuming a maxwell relation will come into play, but I'm not seeing how

Comment: Correct. Use the Maxwell relation associated with the potential differential of $-S\,dT-L\,df$. You'll also need to split another derivative up into two using the chain rule.